# Does using `wget --mirror --continue` as cron job strictly make sure that my files mirrors those in the server?

Tags: windows, apache, cron, wget

I am planning on using `wget --mirror --continue` on windows command prompt (i downloaded a win wget) to keep downloading all files from a server.
It works fine, it downloads, and I am planning to put this `.bat` on my windows `task scheduler` but I have a doubt since I am not familiar with `wget`, since it says `--mirror`. Does it also make sure those files in my `local directory` makes sure it is **Strictly mirrors** those in the server?
Because, what if:

1. I downloaded the files from the server using `wget --mirror`
2. the server deletes all its files
3. I run `wget --mirror` again

Will wget also delete all the files in my local?

Sorry I am not sure, and I cannot test since I do not have my own server.
Just a quick answer would be very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I just tested with a minutely VPS and apparently `wget` **does not** delete them even the files are lost in the server.